# Setting USB current limit on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I have a Samsung Galaxy s8 that's connected to my Raspberry Pi in order to provide an internet connection. I'm looking to limit the harm done to the battery in the phone.

Right now the battery in the phone is always at 100%, which isn't the best for it. I learned that I can't just shut off the power on the USB ports and still be able to pass data between the phone and the Pi.

So, I was wondering if I was able to limit the total amount of power on the USB ports to say 100 or 500 ma and still be able to pass data between the phone and the Pi.

Comment: Why not set the pi up as an access point and use a normal charger?

Comment: The Pi is setup as a router that's connected to an AP. The Pi is tethered the the phone.

Comment: I am inclined to say that this should not be a problem. If it were it would be an ill designed charging circuit in that phone.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if I was able to limit the total amount of power on the USB ports to say 100 or 500 ma and still be able to pass data between the phone and the Pi.

No - the Raspberry Pi cannot regulate current to a user-specified limit.